# Добавить элементу класс, если найден другой элемент

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

На странице есть HTML разметка:

```
<body>
  <div class="page-container">
    <div class="page-content">
      <aside class="sidebar"></aside>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer"></footer>
</body>
```

> Примечание: Блока sidebar на странице может и не быть!

Вопрос:

Как вычислить с помощью JavaScript присутствие блока с классом `sidebar` и в случае обнаружения присвоить класс блоку `footer`?

Comment: можно это решить css ом

Comment: Этот вариант еще лучше. Подскажите!?

Comment: `.sidebar ~ .footer {border:solid red;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*При условии, что у вас только один такой элемент на страницу:

```js
var sidebar = document.querySelector('.page-content .sidebar');
var footer = document.querySelector('.footer');

if( sidebar ){
  footer.classList.add('red');
}
```

```css
.red { color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="page-container">
  <div class="page-content">
    <aside class="sidebar"></aside>
  </div>
</div>

<footer class="footer">Тест</footer>
```

Comment: Это сработает если div идут подряд? А если они еще в разных блоках тогда только JS?

Comment: Поправил разметку! Вот такая будет, без изменений.

Comment: @verstala в таком случае всё будет проще) querySelector находит только первый элемент по этому селектору. Т.е. `.sidebar` где-то внутри `.page-content`. Если такой элемент будет найден - условие выполнится.

Comment: Средствами css такую разметку не решить?

Comment: Без вариантов... CSS-селекторы умеют находить или вложенные блоки, или соседние (ниже в коде)... не умеют "выходить" к родителю и от родителя уже искать соседние-вложенные)

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!